# How can I center the titleicon in a Flex 3 panel?

Tags: apache-flex, panel, title

How can I center the titleicon in a Flex 3 panel? The title is centered but the titleicon is way on the left side of the panel.

```
<mx:Panel  
    title="{myTitle}"    
    textAlign="center"
    titleStyleName="panelTitle" 
    titleIcon="{myIcon}"
    >   


.panelTitle {
    font-size: 14;
    fontFamily: "Lucida Grande";
}
```

EDIT: I'm trying to get www.flextras.com suggestion to work. This is what I've got:

```
package com.mysite.components
{
    import mx.containers.Panel;

    public class CenterTitleIconPanel extends Panel
    {

        override protected function layoutChrome(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.layoutChrome(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
                if (titleIconObject)
                {
                    titleIconObject.move((unscaledWidth-titleIconObject.width)/2,(unscaledHeight-titleIconObject.height)/2);
                }
        }


        public function CenterTitleIconPanel()
        {
            super();
        }

    }
}
```

But, I'm getting Error 1178:

> 1178: Attempted access of inaccessible
>   property titleIconObject through a
>   reference with static type
>   com.mysite.components:CenterTitleIconPanel.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend the component and override the layoutChrome method to reposition the titleIcon.

Roughly something like this:

```
override protected function layoutChrome(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                             unscaledHeight:Number):void{
 super.layoutChrone(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
            if (titleIconObject)
            {
                titleIconObject.move((unscaledWidth-titleIconObject.width)/2,(unscaledHeight-titleIconObject.height)/2);
            }
 }
```

I'm, basically, taking the unscaledWidth of the component, subtracting the width of the titleIconObject, and then cutting that value in half to get the X position of the component.

Then I'm using the same approach for the height.

Since the titleIconObject is positioned using a similar approach, I doubt there are styles that will affect the positioning.

---

The problem you're having with your attempt is that the titleIconObject is put in the custom namespace, mx_internal.  This is a bit of black magic on the part of the Flex team.  But, to access a property in that custom namespace, you have to import the namespace and use it.  This updated code should work:

```
package com.mysite.components
{
    import mx.containers.Panel;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;    

    use namespace mx_internal;
    public class CenterTitleIconPanel extends Panel
    {

        override protected function layoutChrome(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
            super.layoutChrome(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);
                if (titleIconObject)
                {
                    titleIconObject.move((unscaledWidth-titleIconObject.width)/2,(unscaledHeight-titleIconObject.height)/2);
                }
        }


        public function CenterTitleIconPanel()
        {
            super();
        }

    }
}
```

mx_internal is where all the stuff the Flex Team doesn't want to document goes to live (or die).

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thank you for the code. I'm not too experienced with extending components, so I probably screwed something up. I'm getting Error 1178: Attempted accessof inaccessible property titleIconObject through a reference with static type com.mysite.components:CenterTitleIconPanel. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: You're lucky it's no a private variable; I see the problem and will update my answer; give me a minute.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thanks so much for the help. I didn't know about mx_internal (or how to extend components by overriding the layoutChrome). So I'm learning something new. I'm still some problems. The icon was positioned in the middle of the panel. So, I made this change:  titleIconObject.move((unscaledWidth-(titleIconObject.width+120))/2,(titleIconObject.height -20)); . It looks good. The problem is that the length of the title varies and the icon crashes into it. (I have a binding expression on the title). Is there a way to set the icon's position relative to the title's? Thank you!

Comment: I need to figure out how to "grab" the title's width and insert it where I wrote 120 in the comment above. I tried title.width and titleTextField.width, but that didn't work. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: There is a protected variable named titleTextField which I suspect contains the text in the title bar.  You just have to accommodate it's location and size somehow.  So, something like titleIconObject.x = titleTextField.x + titleTextField.width; will put the icon but up against the title text field.  And then titleIconObject.y = titleTextField.y will make their tops align.

Comment: Using the move method it'd be something like this: titleIconObject.move(titleTextField.x + titleTextField.width,titleTextField.y ).  That, of course, is different than centering, but it does position in relation to the titleTextField.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, Thank you for the suggestions. Unfortunately, it pushed the icon all the way to the right side of the screen. I tried subtracting a few hundred pixels from titleTextField.x + titleTextField.width. But, if I put in a longer title, then the icon overlaps it. Panel.as has a private variable called _title. Is there some way to grab the width and x of this private variable? Thanks so much for the help you've rendered.

Comment: If it's a private var; you can't access it's properties in the child.  It is possible, though difficult to extend it.  You basically have to re-create the variable, them override or re-create every method that accesses it so that they are accessing your new var; not the private var in the super class.  It's doable, but tedious.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras.com, That doesn't sound good. I'll have to think of a workaround. In the override function, I can get the number if characters in the title using title.length. (I'm not sure why I can get the length, but not the width). I know that the fontsize is 14 and the letters are upper case. Is there a way to calculate the title's width using this info?

Comment: @Laxmidi The title is a string; and the length is the number of characters in it. Very different than the component that displays the title.  You may be able to calculate something using measureText() http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#measureText()

Comment: @Flextras I understand that the length is the # of characters. I thought that there might be a way to use that info to calculate the width. In any event, you mentioned measureText, which I had tried in the previously without any luck. But, your suggestion made me try it again, and I got it to work. Here's the code: var titleTextFieldWidth:Number = titleTextField.width;
                var titleTextFieldMeasuredWidth:Number = titleTextField.measuredWidth;
                 
                   titleIconObject.move(((titleTextFieldWidth - (titleTextFieldMeasuredWidth - 32))/2), titleTextField.y);

Comment: @Flextras, I ran out of space in teh comment above. Thank you very much for the help. I learned a lot.